# плюс процент к инпуту

Tags: php

```
    <input type="tel" name="sum" >
```

нужно что бы пользователь при вводе суммы добавлялся определённый процент, пытаюсь так не получается

```
 if(!empty($_GET['sum'])) {
$_GET['sum'] / 100 * 2; //то есть прибавлять 2 процента к заданному числу
}
```

Comment: надо умножать `*1.02`

Comment: ну всё равно инпут отправляет то число которое я ввёл, значит нужно делать на клиентской части ?

Comment: `$_GET['sum'] / 100 * 2` - эта строка, может, и считает что-то, но результат никуда не сохраняется. Вам нужно результат вычислений сохранить, к примеру, в переменную, и ее использовать дальше.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!empty($_GET['sum'])) {
    $_GET['sum'] *= 1.02; //то есть прибавлять 2 процента к заданному числу
}
```

Answer (score 0):

сделал на клиентской стороне `<input type="hidden" name="sum"> <input type="tel" id="payment-cost" oninput="sum.value = this.value * 1.025;">`